# How to call debounce correctly? lodash

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a reactNative project and I am having a bit of trouble using the `_.debounce` method of lodash. This is my current code:

```
class GooglePlacesAutocompleteModal extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getPredictions = this.getPredictions.bind(this);
  }

  getPredictions(input) {
    function getAutocompletePredictions(input) {
      RNGooglePlaces.getAutocompletePredictions(input)
      .then(results => {
        console.log('Autocomplete results: ', results);
        this.setState({ predictions: results })
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error.message))
    }

    _.debounce(getAutocompletePredictions, 300);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        style={inputStyle}
        autoCorrect={false}
        maxLength={40}
        autoCapitalize={'words'}
        onChangeText={this.getPredictions}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

I dont see why debounce is not working since I followed the documentation and even understand the function itself. Any help is welcome!

Comment: `_.debounce` returns a function which you don't seem to call anywhere.

Comment: @georg so I could do `_.debounce(getAutocompletePredictions, 300)();` ?

Comment: Note: remember to bind `this` to the returned function.